# How to write a oracle procedure which will automatically count number of files in a folder in linux server

Tags: linux, oracle, stored-procedures

How to count the number of files in a folder in Linux Server in a procedure in Oracle? I got one code for counting the same at Linux terminal. But I want to implement the same in a procedure which will automatically take the count and return.

```
$ ls -l | grep -v ^l | wc -l
```

Comment: which version of Oracle..?

Comment: Its is Oracle 11G

Comment: You can use an external table with preprocessor command. Suggest you to check this link. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2155105300346643982 for details.

Comment: Could you please help me in writing the same as I am bit confused

Comment: SO is not the correct place for "help me in writing" Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I think that would do: http://www.oraclefrontovik.com/2013/08/listing-files-from-a-linux-directory-from-within-oracle-sql-or-plsql-in-11g/